# Can't import PIL and get this error "The use of `load_img` requires PIL."

Tags: python-3.x

```
classifier.fit_generator(training_set, steps_per_epoch = 12000, epochs =100 ,
                        validation_data = test_set, validation_steps = 3000)
```

This is my code..I already installed pillow.

Answer (score 0):

On some installs of PIL, you must do

```
import Image
```

instead of import PIL (PIL is in fact not always imported this way). Since import Image works for you, this means that you have in fact installed PIL.

Having a different name for the library and the Python module is unusual, but this is what was chosen for (some versions of) PIL.

or  PIL is deprecated, and pillow is the successor.

```
pip install Pillow
```